# Calling librosa.grifflim returns an attribute error

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, spectrogram, librosa

In the following code I'm getting errors when trying to call librosa.grifflim, telling me the attribute does not exist.

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display
import IPython.display as ipd
import numpy as np
import cv2

S = cv2.imread('spectrograms/CantinaBand60.wav10.jpg')
D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(S), ref=np.max)
signal = librosa.griffinlim(D)
sf.write('test.wav', signal, 352000)
```

I've upgraded librosa, and I still encounter the error. The documentation page for this function no longer seems to exist either. I've also tried import just that module using librosa.griffinlim but it continues to tell me this module doesn't exist. Was this function removed during a recent version? If so, is there another function I can use to apply the griffin lim algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`librosa.griffinlim` was introduced in librosa `0.7.0`. So you need to have that version or later. You can check this using the following code.

```py
import librosa; print(librosa.__version__)
```